# Which tool can be used to make the same query to mutiple mysql databases with the same structure?

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a multi-tenant application where each user has their own database(MySQL). That means that the database structure is the same. I have found myself in situations where I want to query the whole set of databases with the system live. This is mostly to drop a column, add a column, or delete a row. Is there a tool that can make it possible to apply a single query on all the databases?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.  You would need to use a scripting language to accomplish this.  Would be a pretty simple PHP script.  You would pass in your query and the script would run the query on all databases.

Comment: I'm aware that it is possible to achieve it by writing a script. My interest is finding out if there is a tool out there that can achieve it instead of re-inventing the wheel.